# Schedule the same coding logic with different frequency without creating separate scheduler classes

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I know the question is confusing, let me explain.

I have a scheduler that reads data of a list of points from an IOT device and posts consistently to the cloud. The list of points to be read is obtained from the database and requested to the IOT device to retrieve data. This functionality is working without hassles when **each point has the same read frequency value**. In this case, I schedule my task to the same read frequency (say, 15 minutes) and everything works fine.

However, if the read frequency of a point can be value from this list (1, 5, 10, 15, 30, 60, 240) [in minutes], then the only way I can think to implement this would be write seven different schedulers (one for each read frequency) that run with the same logic of reading data and posting to the cloud.

Is there a way to run the same scheduled task at different rates in Spring, without having to create different scheduler classes for each frequency?

Comment: Do I understand this right: You have a list of (end) points from which you read data, the frequency for reading from each point can differ, and you have some code that initiates schedulers based on this list. What is your problem with creating multiple schedulers? An alternative is to create a scheduler with the highest frequency (e.g., 1/5 if you have freq's 1/5, 1/10, 1/30) and then check in your scheduler which point is due for reading. This adds complexity to the scheduler, so ask yourself if you would want that.

Comment: @MikkelRJ One, no they are not endpoints. They are points, in IOT terminology, for which the device has data. I have a list of points on the cloud. I want to read data for the points at different frequencies from the device. I don't have an issue with creating seven different schedulers, but all the schedulers will be running on the same logic and code - just different frequency and inputs. I was wondering if there was anyway I can reuse a single piece of code instead of creating seven different classes. I have thought of the alternative approach you have mentioned and I don't want to do that.